Underlapping Eze
I can't understand the word "underlap" in this context, can you explain what it means?

Brighton 0-2 Crystal Palace (45+1 mins)
Eberechi Eze leads a Palace counter-attack, giving the ball to Jean-Philippe Mateta who cuts behind Jan Paul van Hecke. Mateta attempts to cross to the underlapping Eze but it's cut out.


Do you know what "overlapping" means? Have you looked up "underlap" in a dictionary?

It means to extend partly under.

Just be aware, this is Sports-Commentatorese, a type of jargon that is very different from normal English. I find football intensely boring and therefore know virtually nothing about it, and I also have no idea what the last sentence means – not only the underlapping bit, but also the bit about something (the ball? the cross?) being ‘cut out’ (of what?).

@JanusBahsJacquet No, underlap/overlap are terms in football (soccer). As soccer is increasingly popular around the globe and there are tons of English-speaking sites, coaches, fans and commentators, this question should remain open. It should read: but is cut out.

@Lambie I wasn’t suggesting the question should be closed – jargon, slang and such things are part of English and perfectly valid topics for questions. I was just making the asker aware that this is jargon, not ‘neutral’ English, so it’s not surprising they don’t understand it, because even a lot of native speakers won’t know what it means.


Breaking Down the Overlapping and Underlapping Runs
An overlapping run
is when a teammate runs around and past the player with the ball. This
type of run can pull defenders away from the teammate in possession or
it can help create a 2v1 passing opportunity for your teammate with
the ball.


With an underlapping run, a player runs inside the ball. As
the ball travels, the full-back runs forward inside the pass. The
point is to run into space beyond where the ball is, to receive in an
advanced position. It also can help to pull defenders away from the
teammate on the ball.
overlapping and underlapping passes_also, see the video at this site
Overlapping Run / Underlapping Run An overlapping run is when a player
runs on the outside of a team mate who is in possession of the ball.
An underlapping run is when a player runs inside the ball.

soccercoachweekly

What does "inside the ball" mean?

See both here: https://www.sportsessionplanner.com/s/iAnci/Overlap-Underlap-Blindside-Run-and-Thirdman-Run..html?interface=en

Ah, inside/outside the player with ball.

@TimR Right. :)
